# Carregar componente somente depois de terminar as requisições HTTP

Tags: angular, typescript

Minha aplicação usa [angular-6-json-schema-form](https://github.com/hamzahamidi/Angular6-json-schema-form) para criar e gerenciar os formulários de forma dinamica. Agora gostaria que o component select, por exemplo tenha seus dados vindos de alguma fonte REST:

Minhas tentativas:

- ForkJoin: mesmo com forkJoin, a componente carrega primeiro que os dados e o componente nao funciona corretamente.
- ViewChild (sem *ngIf no componente, claro): como as requisições get Http ainda não terminaram, ele estoura centenas de erros que até travam a aplicação, se usa *ngIf, a viewChild sempre será `undefined`.

**JsonSchema**

```
    {
      "title": "A registration form",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "users"
      ],
      "properties": {

        "users": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Usuarios"
        },
        "todo": {
          "type": "string",
          "title": "Tarefas"
        }
      }
    }
```

**UiSchema/Form:**

```
    {
      "metadados": {
        "ui:widget": "select",
        "options": {
          "titleMap": [],
          "placeholder": "Selecione",
          "source": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users&field=users",
          "columnName": "username",
          "columnValue": "id",
          "isAuthenticated": false
        }
      },
      "repos": {
        "ui:widget": "select",
        "options": {
          "titleMap": [],
          "placeholder": "Selecione",
          "source": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users&field=todo",
          "columnName": "title",
          "columnValue": "id",
          "isAuthenticated": false
        }
      }
    }
```

**meu engine-form.component.ts:**

```
    ngOnInit() {

      const sub = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
        switchMap(params => this.service.geByCTIformItemId(params.get('form_id'), params.get('form_item_id'))),
        map(res => {

          this.formData = this.loadResource(res);

          const uiSchemaObj = JSON.parse(res.ui_schema);

          if (this.hasSource(res.ui_schema)) {

            const depedencies = this.loadDependenciesFromUiSchema(res.ui_schema);

            depedencies.subscribe((dependencyResponse: any) => {

              dependencyResponse.map((item: any) => {

                const widItem = uiSchemaObj[item.field];
                const columnName = widItem.options.columnName;
                const columnValue = widItem.options.columnValue;

                widItem.options.titleMap = item['data'].map(itemRes => {
                  return {
                    value: itemRes[columnValue],
                    name: itemRes[columnName],
                  };
                });

                this.formSchema = {
                  schema: JSON.parse(res.json_schema),
                  form: uiSchemaObj,
                  formData: this.formData,
                };
              });
            });

          }
          this.formActive = true;
          return res;
        }),
      );
      sub.subscribe();
    }

    private loadResource(res: any) {
      const row = {};

      if (this.route.snapshot.routeConfig.path !== ':form_id/novo') {

        const allowed = Object.keys(res.data).filter(f => !RegExp('^__').test(f));

        allowed.forEach(i => {
          row[i] = res.data[i];
        });
      }
      return row;
    }

    private loadDependenciesFromUiSchema(uiSchema: any): Observable<any[]> {

      const uiSchemaObj = JSON.parse(uiSchema);

      const uiItems = Object.keys(uiSchemaObj).filter(item => !item.includes(':'));
      const arr: Observable<any>[] = [];

      uiItems.map(uiItem => {
        const widItem = uiSchemaObj[uiItem];

        if (widItem['ui:widget'] === 'select') {

          // tem requisicao dinamica:
          if (this.hasValidDynamic(widItem.options)) {

            const req = this.http.get(widItem.options.source);
            arr.push(req);

          }
        }
      });
      return forkJoin(arr);
    }

    private hasSource(uiSchema: string) {
      return uiSchema.includes('source');
    }

    private hasValidDynamic(options: any): boolean {
      return typeof (options.source) !== 'undefined'
        && typeof (options.columnName) !== 'undefined'
        && typeof (options.columnValue) !== 'undefined';
    }
```

**engine-form.component.html**

```
        <json-schema-form framework="bootstrap-4"
                          loadExternalAssets="true"
                          autoUpdateContent="true"
                          *ngIf="formActive"
                          [form]="formSchema"
                          [options]="jsonFormOptions"
                          (onChanges)="onChanges($event)"
                          [widgets]="yourNewWidgets">
        </json-schema-form>
```

Comment: Não seria o caso de você colocar as funções dentro do OnLoad da pagina?  tipo $(document),ready(function(){ sua rotina});

Comment: Acho que seria melhor mesmo usando o ngIf, nesse caso o viewchild tambem só estaria disponivel depois dos dados retornarem. Porque vc precisa do viewchild?

Comment: @EduardoVargas, na verdade, nem preciso, foram apenas tentativas desesperadas para tentar funcionar.. Apenas preciso que o componente só seja carregado quanto todas as requisições terminarem. Quando é apenas um componente por exemplo, funciona, mas não é o cenário comum da minha aplicação.

Comment: Faz um ajax amigo e no success você coloca o conteudo.

Comment: Galera, estou usando angular 7..

Comment: @SamuelDiogo post depois a solução que deu certo. Achei interessante as 2 primeiras.

Comment: ja estou vendo aqui acacio! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Na minha opinião, você tem duas opções, se deseja carregar os dados do server antes de mostrar os componentes, você pode usar o `Router Resolve`, que garante o carregamento dos dados antes de carregar o componente. A documentação está em: https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve. Existe ainda o exemplo na documentação do angular: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

**Route Resolve**

- Na rota, defina o(s) `resolve` a utilizar:

> ```
> const ROUTES: Routes = [
>   {
>     path: '', 
>     component: DashboardComponent, 
>     resolve: {AdminUser: AdminResolver, funcionario: FuncionarioResolver}
>   }
> ]
> ```

Implemente o `resolve`, implemente a interface `Resolve`, de `@angular/route`:

```
...
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
...
export class FuncionarioResolver implements Resolve<Funcionario> {
  constructor(
    private loginService: LoginService,
    private portalRHAPI: PortalRHAPIService) { }

  resolve() : Observable<Funcionario> | Observable<never> {
    return this.loginService.userInfo().pipe(
      mergeMap(user => this.portalRHAPI.getFuncionario(user.codFuncionario))
    )      
  }
}
```

- No `onInit` do componente, nesse caso meu `Dashboard`, eu posso obter os dados previamente carregados pelo `resolve`:

> ```
> constructor(private router: Router) {}
>
> ngOnInit() {
>     this.route.data
>         .subscribe( (data: {AdminUser: boolean}) => {
>         if ( data.AdminUser ) {          
>             this.router.navigate([ '/admin/funcionarios' ])
>         } else {
>             this.isResolvingAdmin = false
>         }
>         })
>
>     this.route.data
>         .subscribe( (data: {funcionario: Funcionario}) => {        
>         this.funcionario = data.funcionario[0]
>         this.isLoadingResults = true
>         this.checkPasswordExpired()        
>         this.getFuncionarioDetails()
>     })   
> }
> ```

**Combine Latest**

Essa é outra forma, use este operador quando você precisar esperar o resultado de mais de uma operação asincrona, olha o exemplo:

```
private gettingApiData = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)  
public isGettingApiData$ = this.gettingApiData.asObservable()

private getApiData() {
  this.gettingApiData.next(true)

  const lastId$ = this.alvosService.getLastId()
  const repSorteado$ = this.alvosService.getRandRepres()
  const estaticos$ = this.alvosService.getEstaticos()

  combineLatest(lastId$, repSorteado$, estaticos$, (lastId, repSorteado, estaticos) => ({lastId, repSorteado, estaticos}))
     .subscribe( result => {
        this.id = +result.lastId+1            
        this.repSorteado = result.repSorteado
        this.origem = result.estaticos.origem;
        this.grupos = result.estaticos.grupos;
        ...
        this.gettingApiData.next(false) 
    })
}
```

- No HTML, use o observable `isGettingData$`, no `ngIf` ( no meu exemplo eu mostro um `progressbar` até que a tela esteja pronta )

```html
<div *ngIf="isGettingApiData$ | async; else showForm">
  <mat-progress-spinner mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-spinner>
</div>

<ng-template #showForm>
   ... aqui vai seu formulario
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 6):

O método get de Http é um método assíncrono, ou seja, após iniciar sua execução, a aplicação inicia uma nova thread para ela, e continua a execução padrão dos demais métodos dela. É muito útil visto que os métodos http tendem a demorar mais que os demais executados dentro da aplicação, por exigirem um tempo de conexão e etc. Porém, realmente, pode ser um grande problema quando se necessita dos dados trazidos pela API para a exibição. uma forma de contornar o problema é pedindo para que a aplicação espere a finalização do método pare prosseguir. Uma solução em Typescript pode ser a seguinte:

Na classe de serviço:

```
async exemploService(): Promise<Dado[]>{
    const listaDados: Dado[] = [];
    const dadosApi = await this.httpClient.get<any[]>(endpoint).toPromise().then(dataApi=> {
      dataApi.forEach(dado => {
                      listaDados.push(new Dado());
       });
    }
    );

    return listaDados;
}
```

No componente:

```
dados: Dado[];

constructor(private service: ExemploService);

async ngOnInit() {
    await this.service.exemploService().then(data => {
      this.dados = data;
     });

    //Métodos que utilizarão os dados da API na inicialização da view
  }
```

Recomendo dar mais uma pesquisada sobre métodos assíncronos e as keywords async/await, assim como a classe Promise e o método then.

Comment: tenso, para resolver de fato, usei a sua abordagem, mas só deu certo quando coloquei um setTimeout de 1 segundo kkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode fazer algo assim

```
loading=true

ngOnInit(){
   seuService.fazerRequest(response=>{
   //suaLogica
   loading=false;    
})
```

Html

```
<componente *ngIf="!loading">
```

Comment: Ola eduardo, obrigado por responder, veja que ```*ngIf="formActive"```` faz uma verificação parecida, modifiquei pra ficar conforme a sua sugestão, porem nao funcionou..

Comment: tenta colocar o this.formActive = true pra dentro do subscribe na primeira linha do mesmo

Comment: Você pode até atribuir false para formActive diretamente em sua declaração, para ela ser inicializada como false. O único outro ponto do seu código que deverá trocar o formActive de false para true é justamente no último callback da última requisição.

Answer (score 0):

Usando `Promise.all()` para casos, onde varios componentes tenham fontes distintas de dados, que foi o meu caso-problema.

Primeiro eu precisei percorrer todos nós do objeto **form** para encontrar quais deles têm necessidade de fazer chamada http GET.

Por fim aguardo o Promise.all() terminar para tao somente poder exibir o formulário dinâmico.

segue uma [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-json-schema-form-dynamic-select-data-form-demo) e abaixo o core da solução:

```
private populateForm() {
    const formid = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('form_id');
    const formItemId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('form_item_id');

    this.service.geByCTIformItemId(formid, formItemId).toPromise().then(response => {
    this.formActive = false;
    this.formData = this.loadResource(response);


    const onInits = [];

    this.form = JSON.parse(response.ui_schema);
    this.schema = JSON.parse(response.json_schema);

    if (this.form && this.hasSource(response.ui_schema)) {
        // traverse strategy
        const traverse = (item) => {

        if (item.items) {
            item.items.map(traverse);

        } else if (item.tabs) {
            item.tabs.map(traverse);
        }


        if (item.options) {
            if (item.options.source) {
            onInits.push(this.callRestService(item.key, item.options));
            }
        }
        };
        if (Array.isArray(this.form)) {
        this.form.map(traverse);

        Promise.all(onInits)
            .then(() => {
            this.form.map((item: { options: any; }) => {
                // deleto options pois o Angular6-json-schema-form se perde ao montar o titleMap
                delete item.options;
            });
            // monta form:
            this.ativaForm();
            })
            .catch(error => {
            // error handling and message display
            });
        } else {
        this.ativaForm();
        }
    } else {
        this.ativaForm();
    }
    });


}

private callRestService(key: string, options: any) {
    if (!this.hasValidDynamic(options)) return null;

    return this.http.get(options.source).toPromise().then((res: any) => {
    if (res.data) {

        const mapList = res.data.map((item: any) => {

        return {
            value: item[options.columnValue],
            name: item[options.columnName],
        };
        });

        if (key.includes('[]')) {

        const parentKey = key.split('[]')[0];
        const parent = this.form.find((item: { key: string; }) => item.key === parentKey);
        const child = parent.items.find((item: { key: string; }) => item.key === key);
        delete child.options;
        child.titleMap = mapList;

        } else {
        const itemIndex = this.form.findIndex((item: { key: string; }) => item.key === key);
        this.form[itemIndex]['titleMap'] = mapList;
        }

    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Você pode **usar o .finally()** na sua requisição, sendo assim, quando você habilitar seu componente após a requisição, terá a garantia de que seu dados estará lá.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).